# what is the error with my python code?

Tags: python

i have this code

```
animal_names, dates, locations = [], [], []

filename=input("Enter name of file:")
if filename=="animallog1.txt":
    data=open('animallog1.txt','r')
    information=data.read()
    for line in information:
        animal_name, date, location = line.strip().split(':')
        animal_names.append(animal_name)
        dates.append(date)
        locations.append(location)   

    print(animal_names)
    print(dates)
    print(location)
```

i am trying to use the data in the txt file to print me the results i want 
the txt file contains the following :

```
a01:01-24-2011:s1 
a03:01-24-2011:s2 
a02:01-24-2011:s2 
a03:02-02-2011:s2 
a03:03-02-2011:s1 
a02:04-19-2011:s2 
a01:05-14-2011:s2 
a02:06-11-2011:s2 
a03:07-12-2011:s1 
a01:08-19-2011:s1 
a03:09-19-2011:s1 
a03:10-19-2011:s2 
a03:11-19-2011:s1 
a03:12-19-2011:s2
```

which is in the format animal_name:date:location

using the above i want to get

```
animal_names=[a01,a02, #till the very end,a03]
```

same for the rest of them(date,location), how can i fix my code so that is my result

I also need to use these lists the answer questions later

Comment: What do you get for output when you run your code?

Comment: Why don't you make an `Animal` class that encapsulates all that data in one place rather than keeping it in three separate lists?

Comment: builtins.ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack @duhaime

Comment: `print(location)` should be `print(locations)`, notice the plural `s`?  And the above the error shows you haven't pass in arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Or

```
def main():
    fname = input("Enter name of file: ")
    with open(fname) as inf:
        names, dates, locations = zip(*[line.strip().split(':') for line in inf])

    print(names)
    print(dates)
    print(locations)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```